# CRON job on OPENSHIFT PaaS

Tags: php, mysql, git, cron, openshift

So I would like to periodically run a script in my application that Im running on openshift PaaS. I would like to periodically delete some entries from my database.
I've installed CRON cartridge and I have put a bash script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

php /erase.php
```

in .openshift/cron/minutely which should run a script every minute. Ive put erase.php in the root folder of my git repository, so I think that there are no errors in code above.
My erase.php looks like this:

```
<?php
try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.*.***.*:****;dbname=track', '****', '*****');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        exit('Unable to connect to db.');
    }

    $sql = "DELETE FROM table";
    $q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();

?>
```

As far as I can see there can't be anything wrong with the above code. Is there something else that I'm missing?

EDIT:
Problem is solved, in bash script the path has to be like this:
php $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/erase.php

Comment: so what is happening by using this code?

Comment: 1. There is no need to used prepared statement in this code. 2. Why do not you try to add some error handling and logging to this code?

Comment: like count or any messages?

Comment: I don't really have an idea how. I mean if I run this php script by myself it works normal. For bash script I don't know how would I add error handling and for what exactly?

Comment: Is the cron script executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute path in the bash script does not seem to be correct. Your repo directory is not the root. You can use [environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#directory-variables) to specify the absolute path to your bash script. As the `erase.php` is in root of your repo, that would be:

```
php $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/erase.php
```

You should see an error log for the `minutely` cron job in `~/app-root/logs/cron_minutely.log`, after [sshing into your app](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/remote-connection.html#connecting-to-your-application), should you need to troubleshoot the job itself.

If the cron job does not seem to be running at all, make sure you have added the [Cron add-on cartridge](https://hub.openshift.com/addons/26-cron) to your app and that your bash script file is executable, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will apply the changes and report. But do I really need to make it executable myself? So SSH and compile it manually? Right now I have only .sh in minutely folder. In openshift's instructions on CRON jobs it doesnt say anything about compiling manually.

Comment: So yeah, the problem was with path. It is not necessary to make script executable since it looks like openshift does that for you. Thank you for your help!